# Styling extruded lines in GE

Tags: api, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

The issue is I need to change the default color and opacity of extruded line's border. Here is an [image](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/images/linestring_example.gif) from GE API.

So, I need to customize the grey 'wall' under the line. How can it be restyled? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically the 'border' of an extruded line is a Polygon object and should be styled respectively.

Below is the sample from GE API with one additional line and one new method ***getPolyStyle()***, which adds custom styling to the 'wall':

```
// Create the placemark
var lineStringPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

// Create the LineString; set it to extend down to the ground
// and set the altitude mode
var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
lineString.setExtrude(true);
lineString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Add LineString points
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.754, -121.835, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.764, -121.828, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.776, -121.818, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.787, -121.794, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.781, -121.778, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.771, -121.766, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.757, -121.768, 700);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.747, -121.773, 700);

// Create a style and set width and color of line
lineStringPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
var lineStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();

/*** STYLING THE POLYGON ('WALL') UNDER THE LINE ***/
lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getPolyStyle().getColor().set('9900ffff');
/***************************************************/

lineStyle.setWidth(5);
lineStyle.getColor().set('9900ffff');  // aabbggrr format

// Add the feature to Earth
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a [LineStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestyle) style to your feature and specify the color.

The polygon color specifies the fill color (inside the polygon region) and the line color specifies the line border for lines, rings, and polygons.

An example with GE API can be found here.
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/linestring-style.html

To specify opacity you need to set the alpha value (FF=full opacity) in the code color in  the *aabbggrr* format as in this code snippet:

```
var lineStyle = placemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
lineStyle.setWidth(lineStyle.getWidth() + 2);
lineStyle.getColor().set('6600ffff');  // aabbggrr format
```